# How can I get in XPath all element with multiple child conditions?

Tags: xml, xpath

Ciao,

I'm working with XPath and I need to retrieve all elements by specific conditions.

Below one example of my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persone>
             
    <persona>
        <nome>Mario</nome>
        <cognome>Rossi</cognome>
    </persona>

    <persona>
        <nome>Mario</nome>
        <cognome>Bianchi</cognome>
    </persona>

    <persona>
        <nome>Marco</nome>
        <cognome>Verdi</cognome>
    </persona>
             
</persone>
```

I need to create an XPath query that return all  elements with these two conditions true:

- The  element should contain one element with content equals to "Mario"
- The  element should contain one element with content equals to "Bianchi"

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved my problem using a query like this:

```
//persona[nome[text()='Mario'] and cognome[text()='Bianchi']]
```

Comment: Shorter: `//persona[nome = 'Mario' and cognome = 'Bianchi']`

Comment: Also note that this approach will fail for names like `D'Angelo`. When you need to search for strings that can contain single- or double quotes in XPath, things get a little bit more complicated.